MariaDB + SSL + symfony 7 + docker = Access denied for user 'app_ssl'@'172.27.0.3' (using password: YES)
I cannot connect my symfony application running on docker to mariadb using ssl.
It Works fine without SSL (using user app instead of app_ssl)
Also used to work fine before upgrading from symfony 6 to 7
the certs are fine since they used to work before updating from SF6 to 7
symfony is based on php8.3
symfony error:
An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'app_ssl'@'172.27.0.3' (using password: YES)

database log error:
2024-07-02 12:25:19 424 [Warning] Access denied for user 'app_ssl'@'172.27.0.3' (using password: YES)

docker compose
database:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: "mariadb:10.9.2"
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - "${SQL_INIT}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_DATA_DIR}
        target: /var/lib/mysql
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_LOG_DIR}
        target: /var/logs/mysql
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_CERTS_DIR}
        target: /etc/certs/
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/localtime
        target: /etc/localtime:ro
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_BACKUP_DIR}
        target: /opt/mysql/backup
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_BACKUP_SCRIPT_DIR}
        target: /etc/periodic/daily
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      app_network:
    command:
      [
        "--require_secure_transport=OFF",
        "--ssl-key=/etc/certs/server-key.pem",
        "--ssl-cert=/etc/certs/server-cert.pem",
        "--ssl-ca=/etc/certs/ca-cert.pem",
      ]

.env
DATABASE_VERSION=mariadb-10.9.2
DATABASE_NAME=db_dev
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DATABASE_DRIVER=pdo_mysql
DATABASE_HOST=database
DATABASE_USER=app_ssl
DATABASE_PASSWORD=pass
DATABASE_PUB_KEY="/etc/certs/client-key.pem"
DATABASE_PRIV_KEY="/etc/certs/client-cert.pem"
DATABASE_CA_CERT="/etc/certs/ca-cert.pem"

users
 select User, ssl_type, ssl_cipher, host from mysql.user;
+-------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| User        | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | Host      |
+-------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| mariadb.sys |          |            | localhost |
| root        |          |            | localhost |
| root        |          |            | %         |
| app         |          |            | %         |
| app_ssl     | ANY      |            | %         |
+-------------+----------+------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.016 sec)

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                      |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| have_openssl        | YES                        |
| have_ssl            | YES                        |
| ssl_ca              | /etc/certs/ca-cert.pem     |
| ssl_capath          |                            |
| ssl_cert            | /etc/certs/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher          |                            |
| ssl_crl             |                            |
| ssl_crlpath         |                            |
| ssl_key             | /etc/certs/server-key.pem  |
| version_ssl_library | OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022  |
+---------------------+----------------------------+

MariaDB [(none)]> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.9.2-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (aarch64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:      15
Current database:
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     10.9.2-MariaDB-1:10.9.2+maria~ubu2204 mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
UNIX socket:        /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         1 hour 33 min 32 sec

symfony doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version:    '%env(DATABASE_VERSION)%'
        dbname:            '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
        host:              '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
        port:              '%env(DATABASE_PORT)%'
        user:              '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
        password:          '%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
        driver:            '%env(DATABASE_DRIVER)%'
        charset:            UTF8
        options:
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY: '%env(DATABASE_PUB_KEY)%'
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT: '%env(DATABASE_PRIV_KEY)%'
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: '%env(DATABASE_CA_CERT)%'
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT: false


my user has correct permissions and was created like this:
GRANT ALL ON db_dev.* TO 'app_ssl'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass' REQUIRE SSL;
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `app_ssl`@`%`;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_dev`.* TO `app_ssl`@`%`;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;


Were you able to fix that? I have the same issue.

after weeks of posting everywhere no; moved to postgres

I did find a solution. My issue was PDOSessionHandler that caused the problem. It seems like this class is also calling PDO without the options which results in a access denied.
